# Android Studio "Cannot resolve symbol 'R' "

Tags: android-studio

I google this problem already but cannot find anything that works for me. I have just installed Android Studio and i tried to build the empty activity. 
My problem is that Android Studio cannot find R.java file so it cannot build. R file should be create automatically right ? I tried to clean / build, reinstall and nothing happends.

It must be a very simple problem but I dont know this environnement at all so if you have ideas, please contact me !

thanks

Comment: just clean the project and rebuild , it should solve your problem.

Comment: No same problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved. If someone have the same problem, go in Settings->Gradle->Service Directory Path and check if there is only ASCII characters in the path. I installed all in an other disk but android studio keep installing Gradle in my C:/user/name/ directory. Change the path and reboot android studio and it will build